# CakePHP - field named 'login' automatically gets converted to asterisks in $Model->find()

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been using Cake for quite some time, and I noticed something strange for the first time today while writing a simple search Behavior. I'm not doing anything complex, just using `$Model->find()`s on different Models after initializing `$Model` as `ClassRegistry::init('Model')`. Everything works great, except I have a database field named `login` in one of the tables. The value of this field returns as `*****` for any rows that I perform a search on! This does not happen while using `find()`s in the Controller or Model, just in the Behavior. Below is my code:

```php
...
...
$Model = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$fields = array('User.login', 'User.name', 'RelatedModel.field1', 'RelatedModel.field2');
$contain = array('RelatedModel');

if($searchBy === "name") {
    //some code and set $conditions
} else {
    //else some other code and set $conditions
}

$Model->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$results = $Model->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'fields' => $fields, 'contain' => $contain));
return $results;
```

And this is what `debug()` is showing:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'login' => '*****',
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'passwd' => 'a291a5c901cf51b75b6a50135ed5a04bc2e90c54',
        ),
        'RelatedModel' => array(
            'field1' => 'XXXXXXXX',
            'field2' => '7002'
        )
    )
)
```

The actual result should be `'login' => 'nsps_2013'`, as it most definitely is when I use `find()` in the `UserController` and `UserModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The Debugger class automatically sanitizes output for you, replacing the content of a bunch of different array keys with asterisks. A full list is available in the [source](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Debugger.html#456).

Comment: I kinda feel stupid now. Should've just gone ahead with writing the view instead of running round in circles with just the `debug()` output. Thank you for the link!